# Python: storing dict inside list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to store the multiple dict inside the list.
dict has the same key.

```
>>> m = {}

>>> l = [] 

>>> for i in range(4):                                                                                                                                                  
...     m["i"] = i+2                                                                                                                                                    
...     m["j"] = i+5                                                                                                                                                    
...     l.append(m)                                                                                                                                                     
...                                                                                                                                                                     
>>> print(l)                                                                                                                                                            
[{'i': 5, 'j': 8}, {'i': 5, 'j': 8}, {'i': 5, 'j': 8}, {'i': 5, 'j': 8}] 

But, I want to know store as below 

[{'i': 2, 'j': 5}, {'i': 3, 'j': 6}, {'i': 4, 'j': 7}, {'i': 5, 'j': 8}]
```

Comment: This is absolutely possible in python. Please provide a [mcve] for your issue, with a _specific_ description of the problem, and the _code_ for what you've tried so far

Comment: Move `m = {}` to the first line after you enter the for loop.

Comment: The marked duplicate deals with lists; you have the same trouble with dictionaries, also mutable.  You appended four copies of the same object to your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = []

for i in range(4):
    l.append({'i': i+2, 'j': i+5})

print(l)
```

outputs:

```
[{'i': 2, 'j': 5}, {'i': 3, 'j': 6}, {'i': 4, 'j': 7}, {'i': 5, 'j': 8}]
```

The problem in your code is that `m["i"]` and `m["j"]` points to the same memory address on each iteration, and thats why you get all the elements to have the same value in `l`

Comment: You can remove the `m = {}` completely as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new empty dictionary in each iteration of the loop.  In your current version, `m` points to the same object throughout the entire execution, so the list simply contains 4 references to that object.